# Qt c++ - Cloning an object

Tags: c++, qt, copy, clone, undo

I've created my own class that holds a Vector of Vectors, each position holding a custom QGraphcsItem (a chart). I'm attempting to create undo / redo functionality, and the approach I'm taking is to using a stack to hold each state of the chart. The two approaches I'm thinking are:

1. Create a clone of the top level QVector, which in turn would need to clone all the sub-Vectors inside it, which would then need to clone all the QGraphicsItems. I figure I can loop through each dimension, create the QVector for the outer loop, then cloning the QGraphicsItem on the inner loop, unless it's possible to just simply clone the base QVector (and inherently clone everything inside - currently everything inside are pointers).
2. Essentially build a new QVector out of the current state of the chart instead of directly cloning the chart. Each QGraphicsItem has get/set functions to retrieve any properties I need, so I could just create a new top level QVector, outer loop to create a new QVector for each row, then inner loop creating new QGraphicsItems, and setting the properties of the original chart.

Is there a straightforward way to just clone one item, which clones everything inside? Or do I basically have to implement my own cloning function and "rebuild" the current state?

Comment: Qt has a undo/redo implementation, have you read that? http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qundo.html

Comment: Note, `QGraphcsItem` is not copible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the comments - I never knew about the Qt undo/redo implementation. I ended up implementing my own for a bit more control.

For future reference for others with a similar issue, I first tried creating a new 2D Vector to hold the "state" of the chart, filled with QGraphicsItems. This worked at first, until the chart was such a big size that generating 10,000 new QGraphicsItems every time the chart is updated, as well as removing the current 10,000 and adding the new 10,000 was unbearably slow.

I changed it up to instead store a 2DVector that held properties (just QColor, a string, etc) of the chart state, rather than the QGraphicItems themselves. This allowed me to just update the chart, rather than completely re-create the chart.